# SQL - When result is duplicated on 2 fields remove all

Tags: sql

When i run this query

```
SELECT

    DT.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
    DT.ROLE,
    DT.TAX_ID,
    DT.EFFECTIVE_DATE

FROM DATA_TABLE DT
```

I get this result.

[image: result]

Id like to remove results where the TAX ID appears more than once for each contract.

i.e This result would be gone. If they had 3 results they would be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think window functions might be the way to go:

```
SELECT DT.CONTRACT_NUMBER, DT.ROLE, DT.TAX_ID, DT.EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM (SELECT DT.CONTRACT_NUMBER, DT.ROLE, DT.TAX_ID, DT.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TAX_ID) as cnt
      FROM DATA_TABLE DT
      WHERE DT.CONTRACT_NUMBER = '551000280'
     ) DT
WHERE CNT = 1;
```

If you actually want to keep one row per tax id, then use `row_number()` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Just a note, I wouldn't reuse `DT` as table alias.

Comment: Ill try that thanks.Will this work for multiple contracts? This is just one result

Comment: @ChrisMaher . . . Your question is about a single contract.  You can add `PARTITION BY TAX_ID, CONTRACT_ID` to handle multiple contracts.